# Pronunciation of "with"

Tags: pronunciation, fast-speech-rules

For me it's quite hard to pronounce *with* correctly, especially when I try to speak faster. For example, saying *with sauce* nearly breaks my tongue.

Do you have any advice for me? Can I reduce the *with* somehow, like saying *wi.. sauce*?

Comment: I recommend our sister-site for [ell.se].

Comment: In normal, rapid speech, I’d probably pronounce _with sauce_ as just [wˈsɔːs].

Comment: The final consonant in _with_ is pronounced variably (/wɪð/ or /wɪθ/), and often deleted in consonant clusters or rapid speech. The only place it's always the same is in the spelling. Of course, this is also true of almost all English words.

Comment: You're 'th' is probably voiced (too much air) and you're tongue is probably tense. Try relaxing the tongue a bit and pronouncing a voiceless 'th'.

Comment: I think I'd say [wɪzsɒs], as one possible pronunciation.  If you have a problem pronouncing some phoneme combinations, it's a good bet that native speakers also have a problem and will often simplify the pronunciation in some way.

Comment: I can't give the IPA for it, and gods only know if this is typical, but I apparently pronounce that consonant cluster by getting about halfway through a normal th and then dropping just the tip of my tongue away from the front teeth to pronounce the s.  (Which is different from how i'd normally produce the s, and has slightly different resonances, so I wouldn't be surprised to find it's technically a different phoneme.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: start by saying "with the sauce"... practice a few times until that phrase is smooth, then begin to suppress the vowel sound from "the", and keep diminishing the enunciation of "the" until it is completely imperceptible, not even the small "bump" between the first and third words. Now it should be easier to transition from the 'th' of 'with' to the 's' of 'sauce'.

Another way to do it: prounounce "this" slowly and clearly, and gradually drop the voicing of the 'i' ( shorten the vowel sound each time ), eventually resulting in "thssss"; now you have taught your brain to slide from 'th' to 's' more smoothly. Finally, try "with sauce" and see how it goes. :-)